# Django: How to arrange template for Django comments and corresponding replies

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a made a Comment model and views and it works perfectly fine. But I am not able to arrange templates so that it shows reply to its corresponding comments or reply. It will be a great help if you educate me on how do I arrange them.

Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    serial = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    theme = models.ForeignKey(THEME, related_name='comments', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='user', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    body = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True, related_name='replies',on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{(self.body)}({self.user})"
```

Views.py

```
def viewtheme(request, theme_name):
    theme = THEME.objects.get(theme_name=theme_name)       
    
    context={}
    
    context['theme']=theme
    if request.POST:
                form=CommentForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                    # Assign the current post to the comment
                    new_comment.theme = theme
                    # Save the comment to the database
                    new_comment.user = request.user
                    if request.POST.get('serial') == '' or request.POST.get('serial') == None:
                    
                        new_comment.save()
                        return redirect(f"/theme/{theme_name}")
                    else:
                        new_comment.parent = Comment.objects.get(serial=request.POST.get('serial'))
                        new_comment.save()
                        return redirect(f"/theme/{theme_name}")
                context['comments_form']=form
            

    else:
            form=CommentForm()
            context['comments_form']=form        
            
    return render(request, 'themes/view_theme.html',context)
```

Template That I tried but didn't worked

```
<div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title">Comments</div>
                            <div class="card-text">
                                <form method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{comments_form.as_p}}
                                <input type="hidden" name="seral" value="">
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                                </form>
                                <hr>
                                <br>
                                {% if theme.comments.all %}
                                {% for comment in theme.comments.all %}
                                {{ comment.body }}
                                <form method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{comments_form.as_p}}
                                <input type="hidden" name="serial" value="{{comment.serial}}">
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                                </form>
                                <div class="reply" style="margin-left: 10px">
                                    {% if comment.replies.all %}
                                        {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
                                            {{ reply.body }}
                                            <form method="POST">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{comments_form.as_p}}
                                            <input type="hidden" name="serial" value="{{comment.serial}}">
                                            <br>
                                            <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </form>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
```

Thank You. :-)

Answer (score 0):

change name of serial input, it must be serial not seral

Comment: That's not the problem, I've corrected it earlier. I've attached to template just to show what things I've tried yet.